# How can I use functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL Server - I want to do

```
WITH DirectReports (parent_id, pos_id, pos_name, Level) AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT 
        e.parent_id, e.pos_id, e.pos_name, 0 AS Level     
    FROM 
        dbo.em AS e
    WHERE 
        parent_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT 
        e.parent_id, e.pos_id, e.pos_name, Level + 1    
    FROM 
        dbo.em AS e
    INNER JOIN 
        DirectReports AS d ON e.parent_id = d.pos_id
)   
SELECT a.pos_id,a.parent_id,a.pos_name, a.Level 
FROM DirectReports AS a  
WHERE pos_id = '634'
```

And I want a function to do it and if it finds `pos_id='634'` then I want to return 'OK' else 'NO'.

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: Very confused on what you are trying to do here. But, does the query run that is posted and what is returned? Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: So your function should *only* check if an entry with `pos_id = 634` exists? Why the whole recursive CTE in this case??